# Showing $dc_f =0$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I need help with the following part of my homework problem.
Let $X$ be  a CW-complex and let $f: sk_nX \to Y$ be a continuous map to  space $Y$. Consider $c_f \in \mathcal{C}^{n+1}(X, \pi_n(Y)),$

$$c_f(\alpha) : = f \circ \chi_{ \alpha }|_{\partial D^{n+1}}: \partial D^{n+1} \to Y. $$

How do I prove that $dc_f = 0$? I believe  that it's some well-known result which is written somewhere so references are appreciated.

Comment: Is $sk_nX$ the $n$-skeleton?

Comment: You might find the result you need in Steenrod's "Topology of Fibre Bundles" in Part III (I don't have my copy with me at the moment but I can check it later)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Theorem 1 in section Obstruction theory in Fuchs, Fomenko *Homotopical Topology*.

The idea is following. Using Hurewicz theorem $d\circ c_f\colon C_{n+2}(X) \to \pi_n(Y)$ can be factored through $C_{n+2}(X) \cong \pi_{n+2}(X^{n+2}, X^{n+1}) \to \pi_{n+1}(X^{n+1}) \to \pi_{n+1}(X^{n+1}, X^{n}) \to \pi_n(X^n) \xrightarrow{f_*} \pi_n(Y)$. But three middle terms are the part of long homotopy sequence for pair. In particular, the composition
$\pi_{n+1}(X^{n+1}) \to \pi_{n+1}(X^{n+1}, X^{n}) \to \pi_n(X^n)$ is zero. Thus, $c_f$ is a cocycle.